# Explain, how `(SELECT "a" FROM users LIIMIT 1)=a` may confirm, that theres a table, named "users"?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, postgresql

I'm learning blind SQLi from website "portswigger" and play labs there.Unfortunately, i don't understand, how `SELECT "a" FROM users LIMIT 1` can return column "a", if there isn't any column, named "a"(may be i don understand something). And why is there "LIMIT 1"(I know what it do, but not in this case)? Full code: `TrackingId=xyz' AND (SELECT 'a' FROM users LIMIT 1)='a` (TrackingId=xyz' is true). In description of the lab it does not say what database is used, but it not Oracle, because there's using "SUBSTRING" in the solving.

I don't know, how to google it, so i come here.

Comment: Your query just return "a"  because you are selecting the literal value "a".. if you select a column name named  a then you need  `select a from users limit 1`

Comment: That's totally incorrect SQL. I suspect that you made a mistake quoting the code. My recommendation is to edit your question and copy and paste the original code.

Comment: But why should i write `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: That looks like only a fragment of an SQL, not the while thing.  And is misspelled as well.  Details matter, even for cybercriminals.

Comment: Note in postgres, `select "a" from "users"` _is_ valid, as `"quotes"` can denote an object (field/table) reference. Further, postgres object identifiers are case-_insensitive_. In MySQL, the case is the exact opposite: object identifiers are case-sensitive, and `"quotes"` denote a literal value.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look correct. With an SQL standard compliant database, the proper way to figure out if there is a table named `users` is

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'users'
```

Note that table names are case sensitive. Depending on the database management system, you might want to query for `users` as well.

If you want to figure out if there is a table `users` with a column `a`, use

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'users'
  AND column_name = 'a'
```

Comment: I talked about column, named "a". I apologize for the incorrectness. I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The whole query probably includes another table (maybe a CTE), which does have a column "a".  If Users also has a column "a", then it resolves to Users.a, otherwise it resolves to othertable.a.  These could lead to predictably different results and so leak information.

Without the LIMIT 1, PostgreSQL could give you the error `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.  Presumably the app server would do something to that error (other than pass it back unchanged to the criminal) which is less informative than the non-erroring case would be.

Answer (score 0):

The predicate `(SELECT 'a' FROM users LIMIT 1) = 'a'` returns true when there's at least one row in the table `users`.

Essentially it's checking for the existence of users.